# I have to run eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv) every time I start my pc for the terminal to recognise it

Tags: path, macos, fish, brew

I use the Fish shell on OSX and installed brew.
Now I notice everytime I start my mac I need to run the `eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)` command again to make it recognice brew.

I also noticed that my fish in my vs code does not recognises it untill I run the same command in vscode terminal.

Is there somewhere it is not saving my path variables or something like it?

Answer (score 1):

See https://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html#startup-where-s-bashrc

You would add to to `~/.config/fish/config.fish`

Or put it in a new file: `~/.config/fish/conf.d/brew.fish`

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is add `/opt/homebrew/bin` to $PATH, it's sufficient to run once:

```bash
fish_add_path /opt/homebrew/bin
```

Documentation for `fish_add_path` [is here](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/fish_add_path.html).

Comment: The Homebrew command also modifies a couple of other variables. See `env -i HOME=$HOME /opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv fish` for what it does.